# Phonegap- how to insert $1,743 into the sql transaction database?

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

How to escape $, from my content? keep getting the same error. Please help.

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'x[i].getElementsByTagName("line4")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue')

```
// Populate the database 
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    alert("Populate!");
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS news');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id, title, line1, line2 TEXT, line3 TEXT, line4 TEXT, line5 TEXT)');

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","news.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("news");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        p_id = x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        p_title = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        p_line1 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("line1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        p_line2 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("line2")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        p_line3 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("line3")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        p_line4 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("line4")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        p_line5 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("line5")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO news (id,title,line1,line2,line3,line4,line5) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[p_id,p_title,p_line1,p_line2,p_line3,p_line4,p_line5]);

    }


}
```

Comment: If you list your for loop like this then you need your valuate inputs.
empty(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;) continue;

Comment: @Marko ReferenceError: Can't find variable:empty

Comment: That means that you have to apply it most likely childNodes[0].nodeValue or nodevalue only

Comment: @Marko What do you mean? It's already childNodes[0].nodeValue?

Comment: I see you're only supporting back to IE5. Isn't that kind of limiting? What about Netscape Navigator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you should try.

```
if((y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("line4")[0].childNodes[0]) == '[object Text]')        
  p_line4 =y.nodeValue;
else
  p_line4 = null; //or assign empty string
```

edited.

Comment: there was an extra parenthesis.